# How do I rebuild a CMake project, after moving it to a new directory

Tags: cmake

I inherited a CMake project, and I just want to rename/move the  directory, but it seems to have absolute paths embedded into it. `./configure` fails, `make clean` fails.

What are the steps needed to rebuild for a new directory? I can run steps in the old directory, before rename if that is easier.

I assume there are some caches I need to delete, but have not found any answers as yet.

Comment: Are you sure that your project is configured with CMake? CMake is not a Make, and `./configure` is not a usual way for write a CMake project.

Comment: If your project is **actually** a CMake one, it should have file `CMakeCache.txt` under build directory. Removing that file will clear caches.

Comment: It seems to have CMakeLists.txt in each subdirectory. Nuke 'em all?  And it looks like ./configure is just a short script that checks for cmake, makes a few directories, and then runs cmake.

Comment: Do not confuse `CMakeCache.txt` and `CMakeLists.txt`. The latter one is written by the project's developer, the former one is created by CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the project's cmake generated build folder, and open CMakeCache.txt

This is `MyCMakeProject/build/CMakeCache.txt`

Inside it, with any text editor, replace every place where the previous project path is with the new absolute path of the project.

An example of a few lines where the path should be updated are the following:

```
CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_REDIRECTS_DIR:STATIC=/absolute/path/to/MyCMakeProject/build/CMakeFiles/pkgRedirects

CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR:INTERNAL=/absolute/path/to/MyCMakeProject/build

CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY:INTERNAL=/absolute/path/to/MyCMakeProject
```

You will probably have many more different lines with your project's name and the libraries used.

---

Alternatively, the build folder could be deleted (assuming build was done inside a build folder) and cmake reconfigured and re-run again.

(if cache issues persists, deleting the `CMakeCache.txt` and `CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache` files should allow you to rebuild everything as a first time build).